# Get Current UID in Firebase for Android in order to display the signed in users' pictures

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to show blog posts for the current signed in user but I'm getting an error which is basically saying that the app can't get the uid of the signed in user. Please see code below. It's only a simple app hence why I've got this code in the MainActivity. 
Before anyone says it's a duplicate question, I've looked through similar questions and tried to adopt the logic of the answers. 
I've set up a query in order to try and get blog posts, with the same uid as the current signed in uid but the app crashes upon start of the app saying that:

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a
>   null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)"

```
package com.example.connellj.flexibilitygymapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mBlogList;

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseCurrentUser;

private Query mQueryCurrentUser;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){

                Intent loginIntent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }



        }
    };

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
    mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    mDatabaseCurrentUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");


    mQueryCurrentUser = mDatabaseCurrentUser.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(currentUserId);


    mDatabase.keepSynced( true );
    mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced( true );

    mBlogList = (RecyclerView) findViewById( R.id.blog_list );
    mBlogList.setHasFixedSize( true );
    mBlogList.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( this ) );

    checkUserExist();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {


    super.onStart();


    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> (

            Blog.class,
            R.layout.blog_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mQueryCurrentUser

    ){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
            // get and set relevant post detail

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
       //     viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());




        }


    };

    mBlogList.setAdapter( firebaseRecyclerAdapter );

}

private void checkUserExist() {

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild( user_id )) {

                    Intent setupIntent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class );
                    setupIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
                    startActivity( setupIntent );

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "You need to set up your account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );


    }
}

public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){

        TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById( R.id.post_title );
        post_title.setText(title);

    }


    public void setDesc(String desc){

        TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById( R.id.post_desc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);

    }

    public void setUsername (String username){
       TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById( R.id.postUsername);
        user_name.setText(username);

   }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
    {
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById( R.id.post_image );
        Picasso.with(ctx ).load(image).into(post_image);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main_menu, menu );
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu  );
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == (R.id.action_add)){
        startActivity( new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class ) );
    }

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout){
        logout();
    }

    if(item.getItemId() == (R.id.action_signup)){
        startActivity( new Intent (MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class) );
    }

    if(item.getItemId() == (R.id.action_profile)){
        startActivity( new Intent (MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class) );
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}

private void logout() {
    mAuth.signOut();
}

}
```

Comment: where you are doing the sign in process ?? are you using google gmail to sign in your users ? , also you need to check which users have access to the data, if users signed in or not , that are things to check on your rules in Firebase console

Comment: Also, your auth listeners are ok , they will be checking if the user is null or not logged in , when your Activity starts, but as i see , i cant see where you are doing the login process and how you are handling it, take in mind that you first need to log the user in with any authentication system that firebase provides, and after that you can get all you need with mAuth

Comment: Thanks. Basically how it's set up at the moment is my login methods etc are all defined in a login activity, in the main activity is where the pictures from the blog are, within the recycler view. So when the app starts, the first thing that is displayed at the moment is the blog feed. I will change this later of course that it it will be the login activity but for now in this main activity I just want the blog posts relating to the signed in user (there is a signed in user from the last time the app ran) so it should pick up a Uid.I can switch users by logging out in another activity

Answer (score 0):

When the user is not logged in yet, `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` returns null.  But you're calling `getUid()` on that null object anyway.  You should check for null to defend against that case.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you show how my code could adapt that logic?

Comment: If I changed the logic of the app/architecture where the Login is the mainActivity and then I had a postActivity which displays Blog posts in the recycler view and got the Uid within here and then displayed blog posts relevant to the signed in user then this should work as it will always retrieve a signed in user?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the logic of the app to loading the login activity on start and verifying log ins this way and then getting the Uid on the blog post activity itself, the application now retrieves posts based on the logged in user as it has a uid to work with.